# OKTA Validating a user session from another app

Tags: session, okta

Using the OktaSignIn widget, I see I can get res.session.token.  Can I use this (or some other attribute) in another app -- with the APIKey -- and validate that this is a valid session?

We just want a simple to use auth system and don't want to set up OpenAuth...

Can't seem to find any APIs that do what I need.. but could have missed it of course...

Edit.  Basically... our front end uses the OktaSignInWidget... then we want to use this in a Bearer token our API Services layer can validate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will work...

> /api/v1/sessions/me

Get id from this.

> {"id":"102wtHeHhr4Q4q4rh2Fjy6pGA","userId":"00u9uwkfyfiz3Y7uk0h7",

Then... this can be passed and using the API key...Issue a GET to...

> /api/v1/sessions/102wtHeHhr4Q4q4rh2Fjy6pGA

Returns...

Session...

The call to /api/v1/sessions requires the API key -- which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you can use the session id to see if the session is still valid on the Okta server by:

1. Exchanging sessionToken for okta session
2. After redirecting back to your app, calling /api/v1/sessions/me to get the sessionId
3. Using that sessionId in the request to /api/v1/sessions/id with an apiToken to see if it's still valid

This will exist as long as the user has not logged out of Okta, but the browser state might be different - for example, the Okta session cookie will normally be deleted when the user's browser closes, while the session might still exist on the server.

Alternatively, to check if the browser session still exists, you could make the validation check on the client side by making the request to /api/v1/sessions/me - the one gotcha is to make sure that CORS is enabled for both the domains your apps are running on so they have permissions to make this request to Okta.

The above methods work, but it does sound like what you should be looking into is Okta's [API Access Management](http://developer.okta.com/use_cases/api_security/) (OAuth2) - it was designed for this type of flow (passing Bearer tokens to your API services layer).

Comment: Cheers.. Actually changed to an OAUth flow today .. works great . tx!